# C++ #define macro for data logging

Tags: c++, macros

I have a `vlog` class that is responsible for printing all the log messages in the program. Each class can include the `vlog.h` header and then use the following code to log data:

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(vlog::lock_log);
    vlog::EVENT(host) << "hello" << " world!" << std::flush;
}
```

I want to change the above code to a simple macro like this:

```
EVENT_LOG_C(host) << "hello" << " world!" << std::flush;
```

The macro should call the lock_guard first and then pass the message to the vlog::EVENT(host) object. How can I define the macro?

**Edit**: I want the whole log msg (which may consists of multiple <<) to be atomic. Each use of `<<` calls the static object and I can not put the lock_guard inside the vlog class itself.

Comment: Why does it need to be a macro, as distinct (say) from an object that supports streaming?

Comment: @Peter: the macro version is more condense and simpler to use. Otherwise each class should first lock and then call the vlog::EVENT. I was wondering if those two actions canbe grouped into one using a macro.

Comment: @MainAm By overriding `<<` appropriately you can lock in the `EVENT` function, and unlock on `flush` or the last element of the streaming chain. You shouldn't use macros.

Comment: @BartoszKP: how do you recognize the last element of the chain? Not all logs finish with std::flush.

Comment: An object overloading `<<` is the way to go. It should also be a temporary. That way you can scope a single statement. `EVENT_LOG_C` will than be a function returning said temporary.

Comment: @ManiAm.   You're mistaken, and (probably) thinking as a C programmer.   If `vlog::EVENT(host)` constructs a temporary streaming object, the constructor can grab any mutex you like and the destructor can release it, so all stream operations to it will be with the mutex locked.   In modern C++, temporaries are destroyed after evaluation of the expression they are in, so the mutex would be released after the streaming operations.  If you need to extend their life, bind the temporary to a reference.   I'll post an answer to this effect shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just stuff the `std::lock_guard` inside your macro, but making it part of the logging expression :

```
#define EVENT_LOG_C(host) \
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex>{vlog::lock_log}, vlog::EVENT(host)
```

The comma operator in there ensures that the temporary lock is constructed before anything happens on the right-hand side, and it will survive until the semicolon at the end.

---

You could also get rid of the macro by having the first `operator <<` return a locking proxy, that then forwards every following `<<` until the end of the expression.

```
// Simple wrapper around the std::lock_guard to ease operator overloading
struct EventLogLocker {
    EventLogLocker(std::mutex &mtx)
    : lck{mtx} { }

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck;
};

// Perfect-forwarding operator << that hooks on the EventLogLocker
template <class T>
EventLogLocker const &operator << (EventLogLocker const &ell, T &&obj) {
    // Log here
    std::cout << std::forward<T>(obj);
    return ell;
}

// operator << for iostream manipulators (these can't be deduced by the
// template above because they're overloaded for different stream types)
EventLogLocker const &operator << (
    EventLogLocker const &ell,
    std::ostream &(*manip)(std::ostream &)
) {
    std::cout << manip;
    return ell;
}

// Stub function, the important thing is to return an EventLogLocker by value
EventLogLocker EVENT_LOG_C(...) {
    return {lock_log};
}
```

Comment: I like the locking proxy solution. A basic implementation would just be a few lines of code, ¿no? It would make a nice addition.

Comment: @rici there it is :)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is lock the mutex within the constructor of a class that supports streaming operations, and release the mutex in the destructor.

A macro is not needed.

For example;

```
  namespace vlog
  {
       class EVENT
       {
          public:

           EVENT() : event_lock(vlog::lock_log)
           {

           };

           template<class T> EVENT &operator<<(const T &v)
           {
               std::cerr << v;
               return *this;
           };            

           private:

              std::lock_guard<std::mutex> event_lock;

       };
  }
```

In the above, for sake of discussion, I've assumed your logging will be to `std::cerr`, and that the constructor of `EVENT` accepts no parameters.   That can be easily changed.

Then all you need to do is

```
   vlog::EVENT() << "hello" << "world" << std::flush;
```

The working of this statement is that `vlog::EVENT` will be constructed first.  The constructor grabs the mutex.    Then the mutex will continue to be grabbed during each streaming operations.    At the end of the statement (actually the expression within it), the `vlog::EVENT` object will be destroyed, and during its destruction the lock will be released.

If you want to have the mutex locked over multiple statements, simply bind the temporary to a reference.   That attaches the lifetime of the object to the lifetime of the reference.     Or construct a named object.